# Write a Java 8 predicate that filters against a value that is not in scope

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to write a filtering predicate that will filter a list based on a value held in a different object, but the object that I want to extract the value to compare against is available at the time that the comparison is carried out, not at the time the predicate is defined.

Here's an SSCCE

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
public class StreamTest {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        DataContainer dc = new DataContainer();
        Predicate<Integer> p = new Predicate<Integer>(){
            @Override
            public boolean test(Integer t) {
            /********************************************/
                return t > 6; // I need this to be t > the limitValue that is available when the predicate gets executed
            /********************************************/
            }
        };

        System.out.println(dc.numberOfValuesGreaterThan(p, new LimitValue(6)));
    }

}
class DataContainer{
    private List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10});

    public long numberOfValuesSatisfyingPredicate(Predicate predicate,LimitValue lv){
        return l.stream()
                .filter(predicate)
                .count();
    }
}
class LimitValue{
    private int limitValue; 
    public LimitValue(int limitValue){
        this.limitValue = limitValue;
    }
    public int getValue(){
        return limitValue;
    }
}
```

The code creates a DataContainer, that contains the numbers 1 - 10 and has a method that takes a Predicate and a Limit Value, allowing you to do things like get the number of elements greater than 5, or less that 9 by supplying different predicates.

However, at the time the Predicate is defined the LimitValue object is not in scope. Is it possible to define a Predicate that can access variables that are available at execution time but not at definition time?

Comment: Pass a `Function<LimitValue,  Predicate<Integer>>` instead of just a `Predicate<Integer>`, which builds the predicate using the value passed in the parameter.

Comment: @AndyTurner my thought exactly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although Function currying like the other answer would give a general purpose solution. Java 8 has a built-in BiPredicate (And BiFunction, BiConsumer, BiSupplier, etc.) interface you can use instead. Here are all the built-in functional interfaces. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html

Currying is basically converting a functional interface with multiple inputs into a sequence of functions that take a single input. Here are other examples of currying https://gist.github.com/timyates/7674005

NOTE Functional interfaces are intended to be lambdas; there is no need to write such a loud anonymous class. Arrays.asList doesn't need an array, just the elements. It's also recommended to use primitive streams like IntStream with an array when dealing with primitives. There can be significant performance impact and it's a good idea to get in the habit now. C# doesn't have such a distinction, but Java is split along primitive/array and Object/Collection types. Basically use the best stream type and functional interface for the job and the intent of the code will be clearer.

```
public class StreamTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataContainer dc = new DataContainer();
        BiPredicate<Integer, LimitValue> p = (t, limitValue) -> t > limitValue.getValue();
        System.out.println(dc.numberOfValuesGreaterThan(p, new LimitValue(6)));
    }

}

class DataContainer {
    private int[] l = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    long numberOfValuesGreaterThan(BiPredicate<Integer, LimitValue> predicate, LimitValue lv) {
        return IntStream.of(l)
                .filter(t -> predicate.test(t, lv))
                .count();
    }
}

class LimitValue {
    private int limitValue;

    LimitValue(int limitValue) {
        this.limitValue = limitValue;
    }

    int getValue() {
        return limitValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

No. But instead of passing the predicate, you can pass a factory which, from a LimitValue, creates a predicate:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class StreamTest {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        DataContainer dc = new DataContainer();
        Function<LimitValue, Predicate<Integer>> p = limitValue -> {
            return i -> i > limitValue.getValue();
        };

        System.out.println(dc.numberOfValuesSatisfyingPredicate(p, new LimitValue(6)));
    }

}
class DataContainer{
    private List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

    public long numberOfValuesSatisfyingPredicate(Function<LimitValue, Predicate<Integer>> predicateFactory, LimitValue lv) {
        return l.stream()
                .filter(predicateFactory.apply(lv))
                .count();
    }
}
class LimitValue{
    private int limitValue; 
    public LimitValue(int limitValue){
        this.limitValue = limitValue;
    }
    public int getValue(){
        return limitValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer from different aspect:

- First of all, `numberOfValuesSatisfyingPredicate` is totally unnecessary. This method doesn't do any extra job, comparing the stream API. It's inflexible.
- Secondly, if you really want it, since you know the value when call the method, so there should be no second parameter `LimitValue`:

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      DataContainer dc = new DataContainer();
      // I think 
      System.out.println(dc.numberOfValuesSatisfyingPredicate(i -> i > 6));

      // is much better than:
      Function<LimitValue, Predicate<Integer>> p = limitValue -> {
          return i -> i > limitValue.getValue();
      };
      System.out.println(dc.numberOfValuesSatisfyingPredicate(p, new LimitValue(6)));
  }

  class DataContainer {
      private List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

      public long numberOfValuesSatisfyingPredicate(Predicate<Integer> predicate) {
          return l.stream().filter(predicate).count();
      }
  }
  ```